# Convert to Curves

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices, hair, path

I try to convert my vertices to curves , but when i go to Object data properties > Bevel > Object and then select my bezier circle i get ugly rectangular broken shape.

[image]
Left : Curve create by converting a line of vertices to a curve Right : A normal curve

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The default Spline Type for a converted mesh is 'Poly' (straight segments between control points, without handles).

After converting your mesh to a spline, set the Spline Type to Bezier, and handle type to Automatic:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a subdivision modifier to your line before you convert it

[image]

You can also convert it to a bezier curve or Nurbs

[image]

If you change it to a bezier curve, you might need to change the handle type to automatic or aligned with the shortcut V

[image]

If you change it to a Nurbs, you can enable endpoint so the curve starts and ends at its endpoints

[image]

Comment: It's better , but it gives me little controls left if i need to adjust the curve ( because of all the new points created )

Comment: @Sakisaki I edited my answer, also you can just start with a Path curve instead of converting a mesh to a curve